# modify the existing array of math sequence

Tags: javascript

here is a code which creates a math sequence perfectly. the only different thing here is that it just round each number in the sequence and at the very end calculates the last number separately.

The output, for now, is this: `[0, 6, 12, 18, 24]`

Now the problem is I want a good way to create another function which sums up the first and second items in the array and modify the existing one like this:

So at first, the code creates this: `[0, 6, 12, 18, 24]`

then I want to sum 0 and 6 and have this: `[6, 12, 18, 24]`

then 6 and 12 : `[18, 20, 22]`

then : `[38, 22]`

and : [60]

Note: each time I want to define different value for sn (sum of all numbers in the array)

**EDIT**: in other words, in the new function I have to reassign these lines again:

```
let a1 = 0;  // first item of the array
let sn = 60; // sum of all numbers in the array
let total_Slides = 5;

var n = total_Slides;  // total array or sequence length
var last = (sn - (n/2 * a1)) * 2/n  // equation to calculate the last number if we want the sum of whole sequence will be equel to sn
var d = (last - a1) / (n - 1)
```

Here is the code:

```js
let reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue;
let reducere = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue;

let a1 = 0;  // first item of the array
let sn = 60; // sum of all numbers in the array
let total_Slides = 5;

var n = total_Slides;  // total array or sequence length
var last = (sn - (n/2 * a1)) * 2/n  // equation to calculate the last number if we want the sum of whole sequence will be equel to sn
var d = (last - a1) / (n - 1) 

var next = [];
var sum = 0;

for (let i = 1; i < total_Slides; i++){
      sum += a1 + (d * ( i - 1));  
      var pusher = int_part(sum);
      next.push(pusher);
      sum -= pusher
    }  
  
  let sumer = sn - (next.reduce(reducer));
  next.push(sumer) 
  let sumerr = next.reduce(reducere);
  console.log(sumerr)
  console.log(next)
 
function int_part(y){
  return Math.trunc(y);

}

function float_part(d){
  let int_part = Math.trunc(d);
  
  return Number((d-int_part).toFixed(2)); 
}
```

Comment: Please modify your snippet to a [mcve] by adding input and expected  output to the snippet. It is not clear what your actual question is

Answer (score 3):

You could get the first two elements, add them ad take this value as first item of a new array and concat all item from index 2 on.

```js
var array = [0, 6, 12, 18, 24];

while (array.length > 1) {
    array = [array[0] + array[1]].concat(array.slice(2));
    console.log(...array);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer... plus one... but my problem is I can't implement it on my code...  please have a look at question's edit...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to replace current elements in the array.

```js
const numbers = [0, 6, 12, 18, 24];

while (numbers.length >= 2) {
  let [a, b] = numbers;
  numbers.splice(0, 2, a + b);
}

console.log(numbers);
```